# How to add Time value/ IST to EST conversion in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add Time value in excel vba.

Label1.caption= TextBox1.Value + TimeValue("14:30:00")

where i will give the timevalue to textbox1 and click the submit button,

The label1 must show the added time value of textbox1 and timevalue("14:30:00").

I want this code because I want to change the given IST time to EST time.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
TextBoxTime = TimeValue(TextBox1.Value)
TimetoAdd = TimeValue("14:30:00")
AddedTime = TextBoxTime  + TimetoAdd
Label1.Caption = Format(AddedTime, "hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your initiative..

But the given code prints the value.
I give 2:00:00 to textbox1
It gives 2:00:0014:30:00 in label1

I want the answer as 16:30:00

Comment: Hi @lan Thanks for your help, But your code does not works.

But I find out the answer.

Comment: Hi @lan Thanks for your help, But your code does n't works.


But I find out the answer.


Label1.Caption = WorksheetFunction.Sum(TextBox1.Value, "09/11/2013 14:30:00")


But one problem is, it prints the value in Double.


I have to change it as Time.


I changed this by pasting the value in a excel cell and formatted it as time.
Is there any code to change it as time in the form ?

Comment: What happened when you used my code. It will work, if you used it properly.

Comment: Sorry it says invalid arguments error and highlights the ":", so i used worksheet function it works successfully.